# Jquery: Enable/Disable based on value of dropdown is not working for dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have a form where I can add new rows to increase the form elements using jquery. In that form I have two dropdown options `(Name:type and accounts)` and two text inputs `(Name:debit_amount and credit_amount)`.

Problem:

I have developed a jquery code to enable/disable text inputs based on the selected values from dropdown options. But the code works fine only if I don't add new rows. If I add a new row it only works for the very first row, I mean it disables/enables inputs of the first row only.

For the sake of clarity I have not provided the code for adding new rows below, but to get a live picture of all my codes please check this link, [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpb5Q/)

Could you please tell me what change should I bring in my code to be able to make all the inputs (including inputs of generated rows ) disable/enable based on the selected values?

My HTML

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
<table class="dynatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Account Name</th>
        <th>Debit</th>
        <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="p_scents">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="type" id="type">
                <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
                <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
            </select>
         </td>

        <td>
            <select name="accounts" id="accounts">
                <option value="">SELECT</option>
                <option value="One">One</option>
                <option value="Two">Two</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" name="debit_amount" id="debit_amount" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

#### Conditions for disabling/Enabling

**1.** If type selected == Debit and a value from accounts is selected then enable debit_amount input and disable credit_amount input

**2.** If type selected == Credit and a value from accounts is selected then enable  credit_amount input and disable debit_amount input

**3.** If any of the values of type and accounts is not selected disable both

#### My Jquery Code for disabling/enabling inputs based on dropdown value

```
//ON the change of accounts(dropdown select)

$("#accounts").change(function() {
    var type = $("select#type").val();
    var accounts = $("select#accounts").val();
    if (type == "Debit") {
        $('#credit_amount').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#debit_amount').removeAttr("disabled", true);
    }
    if (type == "Credit") {
        $('#debit_amount').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#credit_amount').removeAttr("disabled", true);
    }
    if (accounts == "") {
        $('input[name=credit_amount]').val('');
        $('input[name=debit_amount]').val('');
        $('#debit_amount').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#credit_amount').attr("disabled", true);
    }
});


//ON the change of type(dropdown select)

$("#type").change(function() {
    var accounts = $("select#accounts").val();
    var type = $("select#type").val();
    if (type == "Debit" && accounts != '') {
        $('input[name=credit_amount]').val('');
        $('#credit_amount').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#debit_amount').removeAttr("disabled", true);
    }
    if (type == "Credit" && accounts != '') {
        $('input[name=debit_amount]').val('');
        $('#debit_amount').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#credit_amount').removeAttr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: in you fiddle you use live http://liveisdeprecated.com/. and you should be using classes instead of id's id's are supposed to be unique in the dom.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your input elements all have the same id attribute values, ie: "debit_amount" and "credit_amount", so jQuery doesn't know which ones the "#debit_amount" and "#credit_amount" selectors refer to.

Element ids should be unique in the page, so you should append a sequence number to the end of each eg:

```
<select name="accounts_1" id="accounts_1">
....
<input type="text" name="debit_amount_1" id="debit_amount_1" />
<input type="text" name="credit_amount_1" id="credit_amount_1" />
```

Two solutions:

- use the jQuery traversal API to find the input elements relative to the select element that triggered the onChange event. This is brittle and will break if you change your markup too much
- parse the sequence number out of the <select> id attribute and use it to find the <input>s you want to modify

Comment: Though I haven't managed to solve my problem yet, after studying your answer I think I will be able to solve the problem very soon. I am going to use this code to find out the ids `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".target").change(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});`  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Inside the event handler, `$(this)` will be the `<select>` element that triggered the event, so you can just use `var id = $(this).attr('id');` to get the id attribute.

`id` will be the string "accounts_1" etc. so you can extract the number using `var n = id.substring(10);` and use it to build selectors for the `<input>` elements eg: `$('#debit_amount_' + n).hide();`

Comment: Sorry, should be `var n = id.substring(9);`